# Why can't I book xen hypervisor on Ubuntu 20.04.1? panic on cpu 0 timer doesn't work!

Tags: 20.04, xen

As the subject says I simply cannot boot into the hypervisor. I'm able to install it just fine though, it says something about the CPU when I try to boot and quickly just reboots. I have virtualization enabled. The most I'm able to see is that it says panic on cpu 0 before rebooting.

The laptop is an Asus ZenBook

The laptop cannot run in legacy mode, does this matter?

Comment: link to the tut ?

Comment: @ScottStensland https://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Xen_Project_Beginners_Guide

Comment: @wookieluvr - you ever figure this out?